# Android Espresso - combined view matchers for nested parents

Tags: android, layout, nested, android-espresso

I want to find the button with id 'buttonActionNo' from the following view hierarchy.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work. Giving 'No views in hierarchy found matching:' error.

```
**ViewInteraction appCompatImageButton3 = onView(  
            allOf(withId(R.id.buttonActionNo),   
                        allOf( withhParent(withId(R.id.actionButtonPanel)),

                        allOf( withParent(withId(R.id.outerContainer)),

                        allOf( withParent(withId(R.id.questioContainer)),

                        withParent(withId(R.id.redFlagQuestion1))))),

                        isDisplayed()));

        appCompatImageButton3.perform(click());**
```

Has anyone tried to grab a view which has few level of nested parents?

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- redFlagQuestion1  -->
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/questionOneContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/redFlagQuestion1"
                layout="@layout/row_base" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- redFlagQuestion 2 -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/fillerLayout2"
                layout="@layout/fill_space" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/redFlagQuestion2"
                layout="@layout/row_base" />


        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- redFlagQuestion 3 -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/fillerLayout3"
                layout="@layout/fill_space" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/redFlagQuestion3"
                layout="@layout/row_base" />


        </FrameLayout>
```

row_base.xml  view hierarchry as follows:

> +---------->LinearLayout{id=2131492990, res-name=redFlagQuestion1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=780, has-focus=false,
>   has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false,
>   is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false,
>   is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0,
>   y=0.0, child-count=1} |
>   +----------->LinearLayout{id=2131493041, res-name=outerContainer, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=780, has-focus=false,
>   has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false,
>   is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false,
>   is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0,
>   y=0.0, child-count=1} |
>
> +------------>RelativeLayout{id=2131493042, res-name=questioContainer, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=780, has-focus=false,
>   has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false,
>   is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false,
>   is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0,
>   y=0.0, child-count=5} |
>
> +------------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131493043, res-name=questionPanelQuestionNo, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080,
>   height=101, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false,
>   has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true,
>   is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false,
>   is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false,
>   has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=30.0, text=1, input-type=0,
>   ime-target=false, has-links=false} |
>
> +------------->AppCompatImageButton{id=2131493044, res-name=questionPanelUpArrow, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0,
>   has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true,
>   is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false,
>   is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0,
>   y=0.0} |
>
> +------------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131493045, res-name=questionPanelQestion, visibility=VISIBLE, width=960,
>   height=152, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false,
>   has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true,
>   is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false,
>   is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false,
>   has-input-connection=false, x=60.0, y=161.0, text=Is the child
>   becoming less responsive?, input-type=0, ime-target=false,
>   has-links=false} |
>
> +------------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131493046, res-name=questionPanelQestionExample, visibility=VISIBLE, width=960,
>   height=114, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false,
>   has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true,
>   is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false,
>   is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false,
>   has-input-connection=false, x=60.0, y=343.0, text=For example, 'not
>   answering questions' or 'not making sense, input-type=0,
>   ime-target=false, has-links=false} |
>
> +------------->RelativeLayout{id=2131493047, res-name=actionButtonPanel, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080,
>   height=270, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true,
>   has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true,
>   is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false,
>   is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false,
>   has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=480.0, child-count=4} |
>
> +-------------->AppCompatImageButton{id=2131493048, res-name=buttonActionYes, visibility=VISIBLE, width=200, height=200,
>   has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true,
>   is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false,
>   is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=260.0,
>   y=0.0} |
>
> +-------------->AppCompatImageButton{id=2131493049, res-name=buttonActionNo, visibility=VISIBLE, width=200, height=200,
>   has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true,
>   is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false,
>   is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=620.0,
>   y=0.0} |
>
> +-------------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131493050, res-name=txtViewYes, visibility=VISIBLE, width=200, height=49, has-focus=false,
>   has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false,
>   is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false,
>   is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=260.0,
>   y=221.0, text=Yes, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} |
>
> +-------------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131493051, res-name=txtViewNo, visibility=VISIBLE, width=200, height=49, has-focus=false,
>   has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false,
>   is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false,
>   is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=620.0,
>   y=221.0, text=No, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} |

Comment: Hey dush,
I have the same query regarding the nested parent layout on the recycler view adapter.
if you find any solution then share your valuable answer 

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7):

Based on view hierarchry you have mistaked in order of outerContainer and questioContainer.

And I would try different sample of code in onView:

```
allOf(withId(R.id.buttonActionNo), withParent(withParent(withParent(withParent(withId(R.id.redFlagQuestion1)))))
```